# pictureBox, graphics and messageBox

Tags: c#, graphics, picturebox, messagebox

I have some problem with these elements. I try to draw line with graphics and put it on pictureBox. Then I call MessageBox and it runs in back of my mainWindow. Of cause I can't use mainWindow because program wait for clicking buttons of MesageBox. But I don't see it. The button Alt helps me only, or Alt+Tab, but it is stupid. So, this is my code:

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics g;
        Bitmap btm;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Size.Width, pictureBox1.Size.Height);
        g = CreateGraphics();
        g = Graphics.FromImage(btm);
        Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Red);
        g.DrawLine(p, 0, 0, btm.Size.Width, btm.Size.Height);            
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        g.Dispose();
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dr == DialogResult.No) e.Cancel = true; else e.Cancel = false;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = btm;
    }
}
```

Tell me, where is my problem? Thanks

Comment: so What's your question?

Comment: Why messageBox shows behind the mainWindow?

Comment: Your mainwindow is form1?

Comment: You are writing the wrong kind of Winforms code.  It kinda works but it is mostly luck.  There's probably other stuff wrong as well, things we can't see.  As a possible band-aid, there's a MessageBox.Show() overload that accepts an *owner* argument, pass *this*.  Do pick up a book about Winforms, this kind of coding is going to get you into a lot of trouble.

Comment: From last test, messageBox doesn't appear till I press Alt key. Where can I turn off this option? I want that messageBox appears without any additional press some keys

Comment: yes, mainWindow is Form1

Comment: @Hasp, this is full code of simple program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form is refreshed, the paint event will be called. You could avoid custom drawing at this point by setting a flag.

```
bool updatePictureBox = true;

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if(updatePictureBox)
        pictureBox1.Image = btm;
}

protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    updatePictureBox = false;
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(this,"Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dr == DialogResult.No) e.Cancel = true; else e.Cancel = false;
}
```

However, you can avoid the entire issue by drawing within the `Paint` event itself. I suggest doing this instead of using the flag method above.

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;            
    using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Red))
    {
        g.DrawLine(p, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Everything works!!! May be you help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945122/problems-with-printalso-pagesettings-pagepreview

Comment: second example is not good, because then I try to save this drawing to file. so it is neccessary for me to have Bitmap for storing. but I don't understand how can I convert graphics g to bitmap. anywhere writes bitmap b = new bitmap(); graphics g = graphics.fromimage(b). but if i would use g = e.graphics then i get blank image

Comment: You can get and save the image straight from the PictureBox itself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845720/how-to-save-picturebox-image-to-file

Comment: if I use your seconf code + pictureBox1.Image.Save("path"), I get pictureBox1.Image=> null. In this case it isn't possible to draw with e.Graphics. It's necessary only to use Bitmap with Graphics, then Bitmap assign to pictureBox.Image and only then try to save it to file. But for your First example I discovered for myself that I can draw with own methods and without PaintEventArgs, thanks. And I have another question: why when I began using graphics g the speed of drawing fallen compared with the e.Graphics....(in PaintEventArgs)?

Comment: See the detailed answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275365/why-does-painteventargs-graphics-behave-differently-from-control-creategraphics